# Test L4 connectivity using telnet on cmd file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, telnet

I want to test quickly if a PC or a web-server is up and running using telnet on port 80. I've been around for 1 hour until now and came up with the above script that still doesn't work. Is anyone experienced in batch programming to help me?
the execution stop after telnet because once getting on telnet it doesn't enter the 2 other commands, + I think that the telnet need 2 sequential press enter key to run that still i don't know how to do it

```
:abc
@echo off
echo =================================================
SET /P txt=domainin:
SET /P var=Porten:
telnet %txt% %var%
echo GET / HTTP/1.1 
echo HOST: %txt%
pause
GOTO:abc
```

Comment: telnet doesn't read stdin so this can't be done this way. Use wget or curl instead.

Comment: I appreciate but i am on windows

Comment: So? Curl has a windows build as does wget if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: As i sad earlier I just need a simple tool to run as quickly as possible, I can still type the command manually and get the result. I want to stay on "native" windows

Comment: I will try if I can get something with VB scripts

Comment: OK, I understand. That restriction is not explicit in your question hence my suggestion.

Comment: Can you use Powershell? For vbscript check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/91488/578411)

Comment: Also, [hybrid batch + JScript web service checker](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15395490/1683264) using the `Microsoft.XMLHTTP` COM object.  (See the question, rather than the answer, for the solution to your problem.)